# Malibal Lotus P150EM-SE (Clevo P150EM / Sager NP9150) Keyboard doesn't light up after suspend

Tags: keyboard

Hi i have a malibal lotus p150em-se running Ubuntu 12.04 the backlit keyboard is no longer lit after i suspend. Any ideas on keeping it lit after suspend and also if it would be possible to get the other colors my keyboard is capable of working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this driver:
http://sourceforge.net/p/clevo-wmi/wiki/Home/

More information can be found here:
http://forum.notebookreview.com/linux-compatibility-software/708796-clevo-p150em-p170em-sager-np9150-9170-backlit-keyboard-driver-beta-testers-needed.html

Lighting up after suspend, changing colors and patterns, all works for me.

Comment: Working like a pro got my keyboard on random right now thanks so much for this

Answer (score 0):

You can re-enable the backlight by pressing Fn (function) + * on the number pad.

Comment: wow i'm amazed any idea if there is any support now for changing the colors? even if not thanks a ton glad this works!

Comment: System76 released a new laptop (the [Bonobo Extreme](https://www.system76.com/laptops/model/bonx6)) that appears to use the same keyboard. I downloaded their newest system76-driver and the previous one from their website and did a two-way diff, but did not see any changes that would cause the keyboard backlight to work.

Comment: does it work to switch out the colors? I would love to be able to change the keyboard colors under ubuntu